# Scala - Filter Col X from Vector

Tags: scala

I have a scala object as below -

```
scala> f1.getClass
res20: Class[_ <: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame] = class org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

scala> f1.printSchema
root
 |-- features: vector (nullable = true)

scala> f1.take(1)
res23: Array[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = Array([[264960.0,0.17798793528582932,0.0,3.0,44625.0,3.0,3.0,1.0,0.0,1.4046526E10,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,0.0,4.2139578E10,0.0]])
```

Now, in my vectors, one column - Col 8 has infinity in value and i want to filter these rows out. Any idea how to work on Array of Vectors. I tried to convert the vector to a DF, but that didnt help.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to filter on your condition: `f1.filterNot(v => v(7).isInfinite())` (7 is assuming your Col enumeration starts at 1).